# Download photos from Telegram channel history without file_id

Tags: api, telegram

I want to download all photo from channel. Try to use https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto to get channel message history:

```
$MadelineProto->messages->getHistory([
    'peer' => "-100xxxxxx",
    'offset_id' => 0,
    'offset_date' => 0,
    'add_offset' => 0,
    'limit' => 25,
    'max_id' => 1000,
    'min_id' => 0,
    'hash' => 1,
]);
```

As a result I get an array of messages with media:

```
array(13) {
    ["_"] => string(7) "message"
    ["out"] => bool(false)
    ["mentioned"] => bool(false)
    ["media_unread"] => bool(false)
    ["silent"] => bool(false)
    ["post"] => bool(false)
    ["id"] => int(38)
    ["from_id"] => int(500100000)
    ["to_id"] => array(2) {
        ["_"] =>string(11) "peerChannel"
        ["channel_id"] =>int(1369700000)
    }
    ["date"] => int(1520150410)
    ["message"] => string(0) ""
    ["media"] => array(2) {
        ["_"] =>string(17) "messageMediaPhoto"
        ["photo"] =>array(6) {
            ["_"] => string(5) "photo"
            ["has_stickers"] => bool(false)
            ["id"] => int(5251753100000000000)
            ["access_hash"] => int(-6118957000000000000)
            ["date"] => int(1520150405)
            ["sizes"] => array(4) {
                [0] =>array(6) {
                    ["_"] => string(9) "photoSize"
                    ["type"] => string(1) "s"
                    ["location"] => array(5) {
                        ["_"] =>string(12) "fileLocation"
                        ["dc_id"] =>int(2)
                        ["volume_id"] =>int(235100000)
                        ["local_id"] =>int(250000)
                        ["secret"] =>int(5193339136300000000)
                    }
                    ["w"] => int(90)
                    ["h"] => int(67)
                    ["size"] => int(1078)
                }
                ....
```

Now I want to download this file and didnt known how do it. Method https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile request **file_id** but I havent it.

Message history only give me this photo parameters:

- id
- access_hash
- dc_id
- volume_id
- local_id
- secret

How can I get file_id or generate it from available data?

Or how can I download photo from channel history by another way?

Comment: It's different level. The former is Client API, the latter is Bot API.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks... And how should I download photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MadelineProto has undocumented functions like **download_to_file** or **download_to_dir**.

```
$MadelineProto->download_to_dir($message['media'], $pathtodir)
```